# Git authentication - pull as a new user

Tags: git, git-pull

The following set of commands worked correctly

```
$ mkdir carboncake
$ cd carboncake
$ git init
$ git remote add origin gitosis@myserver.net:repositories/carboncake.git 
$ git pull
```

But when i tried pull as a different user,

```
$ mkdir carboncake
$ cd carboncake
$ git init
$ git remote add origin mithun@myserver.net:repositories/carboncake.git 
$ git pull
```

I got the following error

```
fatal: 'repositories/carboncake.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

my `gitosis.conf` contains

```
[gitosis]

[group team]
writable = sweepshots
members = git_id_rsa

[group gitosis-admin]
writable = gitosis-admin
members = git_id_rsa


[repo carboncake]
description = A brand new app by Mithun.
owner = Mithun P

[group carboncake]
writable = carboncake
members = mithun @core
```

and the `keydir` contains
`git_id_rsa.pub KEY-----.pub mithun.pub mithun-rsa-key-20110427.pub`

and the user's `.ssh` dir contains

```
mithun@testserver:~$ ls .ssh/
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  mithun_rsa  mithun_rsa.pub
```

-- UPDATE

I tried `$ git remote add origin mithun@myserver.net:carboncake.git` too, but the same error.

Actually carboncake.git is located at `/srv/gitosis/repositories/carboncake.git`

Comment: That is normal: you are bypassing gitosis by trying a ssh with mithun user, as explained in my answer. You need to use gitosis user always, but the user will be detected because of his public key fetched by git in his `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: That is what it takes to clone/fetch/push a repo as a different user with gitosis: your HOME change, and the public key sent to gitosis changes. But the account used for the ssh session remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mithun@myserver.net` ?

By using `mithun@myserver.net`, you are bypassing gitosis completely, since the correct url would involve the '`git`' user under which gitolite has been installed.
Every gitosis commands would involve the same 'git' user: `gitosis@myserver.net` (assuming a 'gitosis' account here).

Plus, you shouldn't have to specify the full path of the repo:

```
 git remote add origin gitosis@myserver.net:carboncake.git
```

Comment: is it not possible to check out as different user? but why there is groups and members in the gitosis.conf file?

Comment: @Mithun: It is absolutely possible, you just need to be logged as a user with a $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub public ssh key specific for that user, with said public keys published in the gitosis repo. Gitosis will then identify the remote user for the ssh request as said different user. But the ssh request itself is *always* done as 'gitosis' account. Unless you want to bypass gitosis entirely. Only the gitosis account contains the `ssh/authorized_keys` file with all your users public keys in it (and the forced command to call the gitosis script).

Comment: @Mithun: see gitosis README: http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=blob;f=README.rst;h=92047762c38cdf018a901b48a5a092796f51500e;hb=master: "For now, `gitosis` uses the `HOME` environment variable to locate where to write its files. If you use `sudo -u` without `-H`, `sudo` will leave the old value of `HOME` in place, and this will cause trouble. There will be a workaround for that later on, but for now, always remember to use `-H` if you're sudoing to the account.

Comment: Note, that you can specify another public key in `$HOME/.ssh/config`, so that one user can than connect with two different identities.

Comment: @Jan: but that would suppose to define a `~/.ssh/config` file where you would name those two ssh session, each one referencing explicitly a private key through `IdentityFile`. That way, you don't have to use any exotic options when using ssh: `ssh mySshSession:mysever/...`, with `mySshSession` referencing the gitosis user, the gitosis server and the desired private/public key.

Answer (score 3):

To add a little plain-english clarity to @VonC's (entirely correct) answer...

gitosis (which is no longer in active development and you should be using gitolite, but this answer applies to both of them) stores each user's public keys in (in your case) `~gitosis/.ssh/authorized_keys`. When a user ssh'es to the account `gitosis`, ssh does a cryptographic handshake, finds a line in that authorized_keys file that matches the provided key, and does whatever that line says to do. If you look at that authorized_keys file, each line supplies a command to call when that user logs in, which is a call to the gitosis process, carrying the name of the user in question.

So each user is REALLY ssh'ing to the SAME `gitosis` "machine" account, but the key they SSH there with fires up gitosis AS the user they are. That's how gitosis knows which user it's talking to even though they've logged into the same "machine" account named `gitosis`.

So every local repo you want to track to gitosis needs to be given a remote of the format `gitosis@your.server:<reponame>.git`.

Comment: +1. Gitosis like gitolite are based on the ** [ssh forced command mechanism (see link)](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858) ** in order to: a/ authenticate the remote user through the public key, b/ always call the gitosis script for authorization purpose, denying the user with an interactive ssh session as 'gitosis', and fully protecting the repositories (especially if the homedir of gitosis account is in 700!).